# Variance with an array of doubles

Tags: java, arrays, math

I am tasked to create a program where i am supposed to to store the 10 numbers in an array of doubles. Then i have to calculate mean, variance, and standard deviation.
Everything works fine besides the variance and, in turn, the standard deviation (i believe the code works for Std Dev).

I have put copied a sample output and a desired output for your convenience.
Thank you!

```
 package Statistics;
    
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Statistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        double values[] = new double[10];

        //Declaring variables
        double sum1 = 0.0, mean;
        double variance, sum = 0.0;
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner to allow user to input
        System.out.print("Enter the 10 numbers: ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    
        values[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
        {
        sum1 += values[i];
        }
        mean = sum1 / values.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
        {
        sum += Math.pow(values[i] - mean, 2);
        }
        
        variance = sum / (values.length - 1);
        double standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(variance);


        System.out.printf("\nMean : %.1f", mean); //calculate mean
        System.out.printf("\nVariance : %.2f", variance); //calculate variance 
        System.out.printf("\nStandard Deviation : %.2f", standardDeviation); //calculate StdDev
        
        scanner.close(); //close the scanner
        }

        }
```

Desired Output:

```
 Enter the 10 numbers: 5
    8
    10
    6
    12
    3
    5
    7
    9
    -2

Mean : 6.3
Variance : 14.01
Standard Deviation : 3.74
```

Sample output:

```
Enter the 10 numbers: 5
8
10
6
12
3
5
7
9
-2

Mean : 6.3
Variance : 15.57
Standard Deviation : 3.95
```

Comment: `variance = sum / (values.length);` will work :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong formula for variance. Instead of `variance = sum / (values.length - 1);` try `variance = sum / values.length;` and you should get:

```
Mean : 6.3
Variance : 14.01
Standard Deviation : 3.74
```

Answer (score 0):

The variance formula is sum / the length of values. Your std depends on the variance for the correct answer. Hence, why both are incorrect. If space isn't a concern - try doing each step a line at a time, then combine them to once it is working.